# <Warning>: The value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled is currently set to FALSE

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

This is the full version of the warning I received:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o47ez.png)

But I have done exactly what it takes and I keep getting this error.

[image: Info.list]

[Info.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXXEn.png)

I did everything in the documentation, and although I searched for answers on the Internet, the same answers were always given. I tried all of them but I couldn't find a solution. How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Please replace the picture of the error and the picture ofd the Info.plist with the actual text, copied and pasted into the question. Pictures can't be searched or referenced, they are harder to read, and they are much hard to post.